# running G-WAN on RHEL5?

Tags: compatibility, rhel5, g-wan

I would like to try G-WAN but our server runs on RHEL5. I understood G-WAN needs glibc 2.11 (GLIBC_2.6) in G-WAN 3. Is there a version for RHEL5, source code, G-WAN 2 or any other way around this?

Comment: Hot about unpacking later glibc to a directory and using LD_LIBRARY_PATH or unpacking RHEL6 to a directory and using chroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too.  Here's the deal.. glibc needs to be upgraded, this is system-wide.  If you upgrade it you'll end up breaking LOTS of other things.

My suggestion is to either upgrade RHEL, try it in a virtualized environment on the RHEL install, or see if you can do it on a different machine.

For my case, we ended up migrating to a different machine.

Comment: You may want to look at this other (more recent) reply of the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559098/which-linux-kernels-and-linux-distros-are-supported-by-g-wan/13562162#13562162

Comment: Great work, Gil!  The G-WAN team's responsiveness and attention is excellent.  Do we have an ETA on when we'll get access to the next G-WAN version?

Answer (score 2):

What is the GLIBC version for `RHEL5`?

Looking at the latest G-WAN machine code, I found only a few calls for GLIBC > 2.0 so this could be resolved with dynamic linking. I will try to make it work for the next release but to be 'sure' that it will work for you we need to know your version of GLIBC.

Comment: I think this is a matter of compilation.  ./gwan: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by ./gwan)

Comment: These are found in RHEL5.8, glibc-2.5-81: $ strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_PRIVATE

Comment: Thank you anttir, that confirms the idea that, to be 'safe', only a GLIBC calls should receive a special treatment.